# Clear (not delete) all NamedRanges in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

I have tons of NamedRanges in my spreadsheets. 
Those are the Areas where I enter data. 
How could I do a function to clear ALL values in ALL namedRanges at once?
(All I found so far is this, but it just clears one specific range)

```
  function clearRange1() { 
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('B7:G7').clearContent();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do something like this. I didn't see any way to progamatically get the names of all of the ranges in a spreadsheet. If there is a function that will do that, it would be great to know about it.

```
function clearAllNamedRanges() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var namedRanges = [ "Sheet1!A3:B5",
                      "RangeName1",
                      "MyFunSheet!C5:H26" ];

  namedRanges.forEach(function(rangeName) {

    ss.getRangeByName(rangeName).clearContent();

  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that already helped!. Since I have to trigger it from another sheet, I tried setting ss like this: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('JAN');` however, that gives me an error: **Funktion getRangeByName Object Sheet not found** you have an idea why?

Comment: The `getSheetByName()` function is only available on the `Spreadsheet` object. I believe named ranges are unique across a `Spreadsheet`. Which means you don't need the `Sheet` to access the named range. You can put _all_ named ranges across the entire spreadsheet into that array and it will clear those ranges for you. Hopefully that is a little clearer.